# Python post request not receiving any response

Tags: post, python-requests, request

Overall Process: Will upload zip file to the REST API, they process and give back the response code and response text.

It is working properly with small file. Within few seconds receives the response.
When I try to upload large file, Its not showing any response. But from the third party we got to know file has received. And they sent the response after 8 to 10 mins, that is not received into python.

```
headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'
        }
with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
    files = {'file': file}
    response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, files=files)
```

Please suggest some options to overcome this. what may be the reasons

Comment: specify a long (indefinite) timeout in your call


`response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, files=files, timeout=None)`